# 505 / cancel status with jquery ajax (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Working with **jquery ajax** in **Codeigniter** framework.

Sending ajax request as below (onclick of a button)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "user_registration",
    data: {
        first_name: first_name,
        middle_name: middle_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        position: position,
        company_name: company_name,
        address_line1: address_line1,
        address_line2: address_line2,
        phone_number: phone_number,
        fax_number: fax_number,
        mobile_number: mobile_number,
        email_id: email_id,
        company_website: company_website,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        news_letter: news_letter
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        $("#please_wait").hide();
        $("#registration_results").html(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Possible solutions i found in different forums are as below

1. CSRF security should be disabled (Changed **TRUE** to **FALSE** in config file)
2. Tried to send the request with **dataType:jsonp** and also with **dataType:json**.
3. As i am using onclick method placed **return false** at the end of the function.
4. used  **security->get_csrf_token_name() ?> : 'security->get_csrf_hash() ?>** in **data{}**.

I tried with all the above ways. But still i am getting **505 / cancel** status.

**Note :** Previously (some couple of days back) this code is working fine, but now it is giving trouble. Ajax requests with the same format in other pages are working fine.

Please suggest me what may be the problem.

Thanks sreeram,

Comment: IF you run your ajax as a normal php file, does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: Probably you should concentrate on your 4th solution. <?=security->get_csrf_token_name() ?> : 'security->get_csrf_hash() ?>

Comment: @Arun Bs : Just now one more i tried But still same status is showing

Comment: @Naruto : Sorry didnt get you question.

Comment: ok fine.. just check without sending any data..

Comment: @Sreeram My point is, ajax is just a php file that you call on runtime. What does that php file do when you just run only that file, so surf to that file and see if you get the desired output?

Comment: @Arun BS: I tried without any data. Still same result.

Comment: @Naruto : I am calling a controller which will insert the values into database and and in return will throw some jquery code to the present page.

Comment: bro this might help you --> aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20

Comment: @ArunBS : I will try it. Anyway thanks for your Effort.